# How to convert the json results to array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to convert the Json response to array using JavaScript .

```
I have the json response which is :

["simmakkal madurai","goripalayam madurai"].

now I want to change this results to array format .
```

So, How to I convert the json result to array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
var obj = $.parseJSON('["simmakkal madurai","goripalayam madurai"]');
```

If you `alert(obj[0])`, you will get answer as `simmakkal madurai`

Comment: No its not convert into array.

Comment: This syntax is for jQuery. Not sure you're using that.

Comment: No problem, I love jQuery. It's not in his tags and he says it's not working for him. Just thought I'd point it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = JSON.parse('["simmakkal madurai","goripalayam madurai"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,

if your response is

```
var res = '["simmakkal madurai","goripalayam madurai"]';
```

Then you just need to do

```
var arr = JSON.parse(res);
```

Alternativly you could do an eval but evals are never realy recommended, but since you are going from server side to client side (php -> javascript) it wouldnt the the worst thing.
Anyways JSON.parse should work